# Doesn't compile Assembly directivies

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

Im using Flat Assembler, and when I want to run something, it writes: " illegal instruction" to every line of the assembler directives.
For example in the code below, it would write that `.MODEL SMALL` is not legal, and if id delete this line it would write that `.STACK 200H` is not legal and so on.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 200H
.DATA

.CODE
start:
    mov ax, @DATA
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

END start
```

and for this code it works:

```
start:
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
```

Comment: Something tells me you haven't even considered reading the assembler's documentation and are assuming it's going to support what another assembler supports.

Comment: No I didnt, the book im reading didnt specify i should change/do something with this assembler, so i just wrote...

Comment: That's TASM or MASM syntax and directives, FASM does not support them. Get the right assembler or learn how to use this one.

Comment: For those who don't like MS, Japheth's JWASM should handle it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one single standard about the directives of the different assemblers. There are many of them.

The directives of FlatAssembler (FASM) are described in details in [FASM programmer's manual](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual), which is located on public and accessible web page.

Also, this manual should be provided for you in the downloaded package as PDF or TXT file, depending on the target OS of the package.

It covers all assembler directives and supported instructions. There are also, many examples and if something is still not clear, you can ask on [FlatAssembler message board](http://board.flatassembler.net).

In the case of the questioned code, FASM code will look like this:

```
format MZ
entry _CODE:start
stack 200H

segment _DATA

segment _CODE

start:
    mov ax, _DATA
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
```

But, considering that this program is too simple to be compiled to MZ executable (which is suitable for applications with code+data bigger than 64Kbyte) I would suggest more simple COM file format to be used:

```
    org 100h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
```